# How can I have multiple states in the javascript array only when it's pressed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, state

I made a to-do app that has `Incompleted`, `Completed`, and `Deleted` sections. Each `Incompleted`and `Completed` section has `onClickDelete` buttons, and when it's pressed, the task is supposed to be sent to the `Deleted` section.
However, it is sent to the `Deleted` section but it always contains an empty task. I know that my code is successfully pushing multiple states in the array but not sure how to fix it.

I tried
`const newDeletedTodos = [...deleteTodos, incompeleteTodos[index],completeTodos[index]]`

or
`const newDeletedTodos = [...deleteTodos, incompeleteTodos[index]||completeTodos[index]]` but didn't work.

I appreciate any advice!

```js
  const onClickDelete = (index) => {
    //works fine
    const newTodos = [...incompeleteTodos]
    newTodos.splice(index, 1) 

    //works fine
    const newCompletedTodos = [...completeTodos]
    newCompletedTodos.splice(index, 1)

    //Works strange.
    const newDeletedTodos = [...deleteTodos]
    newDeletedTodos.push(incompeleteTodos[index])
    newDeletedTodos.push(completeTodos[index] )

    setIncompleteTodos(newTodos)
    setCompleteTodos(newCompletedTodos)
    setDeleteTodos(newDeletedTodos)
  }
```

Comment: If you call `onClickDelete` when an uncompleted task is deleted, it is possible that `completeTodos[index]` is `undefined`, the same goes for `newTodos[index]`

Comment: You've probably made this more complicated then it as to be, you could just keep all the todos in a single array and add an extra property like `state` and have that set to `Uncompleted`, `Completed` or `Deleted`

Comment: This todo app itself is a little complicated since it also has a `Deleted` section, not just `Completed`. For the `onClickDelete`, what would be the solution?

Comment: Having a `Deleted` section doesn't make any difference, my suggestion will still work. If you want to keep it like this, you'll need to either have two delete functions or use only this function and inside it, differentiate from what array to remove an item and add it to the deleted array, you cannot remove an item from both array and add them to the deleted array since you've only deleted an uncompleted or completed todo not one of each.

Comment: I think I understand what you meant, supplemented by the answer from Himanshu below, but not sure how to refactor it. I will make 2 different Delete buttons and apply for each for now, and revisit here later. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

as per @titus suggestion, you state can be like

```
const [todos, SetTodos] = useState<{ id: string; 
                                    text: string; 
                                    state: "uncomplete"| "complete"| "deleted" }>([])


const onClickDelete = (id) => {
 SetTodos(prev => prev.map(x => x.id === id ? {...x, state: 'deleted'} : x ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For React state updates that depend on the previous value, the callback argument must be used.
This is due to the asynchronous nature of state updates ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous))

Eg. to remove an element.

```
var index = 5;
setTodos((todos)=>(
   todos.filter((t,i)=> (
       index != i
   )
)
```

Similiary `concat` can be used to append to the array.